# Save & restore a real device's state, similar to emulator snapshot

Tags: boot

I am just wondering, is it possible to save & restore a real device's state, similar to [emulator snapshots](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots)?

By using snapshot, we don't need to boot at every time and can just continue from last state (e.g. last opened app or wherever you were left) of the device. This can be very handy on power failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you're describing is something like the "hibernate" option you get on PCs. It would need support from the kernel and the userspace parts of Android. Since 4.2, the boot process on Android has been a lot faster on real devices, so typically it would be slower to boot from hibernation than to boot in the conventional way.

Comment: Yes basically i need hibernate option, slow or fast boot is not important i need to see where Android was left. Is there any kernel you know that support "hibernation"?

Comment: Linux itself has a hibernation feature called "swsusp", but I don't think anybody turns it on for Android, because as I say, it would also need userspace support.

Comment: thanks i'll digg deeper to find a way around like saving the last state of device so that booting may continue from that state